# Create a job from dbms_scheduler with stream redirection?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, jobs, scheduled-tasks

I want to create a simple job who have to execute this shell command:

```
echo some_text > some_file
```

The attributes `some_text` and `some_file` can change between two calls to `run_job` so I need to use `set_job_argument_value` procedure.

Here is my code:

```
exec dbms_scheduler.create_job('write_file','executable','/bin/echo',1,auto_drop=>false);
exec dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('write_file',1,'text > /tmp/file');
exec dbms_scheduler.run_job('write_file');
```

I begin by creating the job who will execute the `echo` command. This job will take only argument : `text > /tmp/file`.
When I run my job, the procedure works fine but my file is not created. It's like the procedure runs this command: `/bin/echo "text > /tmp/file"`.

So I tried with multiples arguments:

```
exec dbms_scheduler.create_job('write_file','executable','/bin/echo',3,auto_drop=>false);
exec dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('write_file',1,'text');
exec dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('write_file',2,'>');
exec dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('write_file',3,'/tmp/file');
exec dbms_scheduler.run_job('write_file');
```

Same output and no file created.

So, is it possible to specify the standard input? Or to use this kind of *job_action*: `/bin/echo $1 > $2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a patch to this problem. The idea is to create a bash file:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
echo $1 > $2
```

And now, you can create and run your job:

```
exec dbms_scheduler.create_job('write_file','executable','/usr/bin/oracle/transfer',2,auto_drop=>false);
exec dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('write_file',1,'some_text');
exec dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value('write_file',2,'/tmp/some_file');
exec dbms_scheduler.run_job('write_file');
```

And you can see the result:

```
$ cat /tmp/some_file
some_text
```